# Operations with dates in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, date

How do operations with dates in cakephp?

I want to calculate the difference in days between two dates, for example: a date subtracting 10 days or a date and add 20 days.

How I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
CakeTime::format('r', '+20 days', true);
```

Take a look on this: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/time.html

Maybe you wan't see this one too: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.phpenter

Comment: Thanks. But I dont find a way to calculate the diference between 2 dates. Ex: reaming 10 days to (date). you can help me?

Comment: I recomend you to use CakeTime::format() to format your dates to php format and compare with php.